# Durandal relative path

Tags: routes, durandal

I'm using Durandal 2.1 to develop an (web) app and loving it. Since installing VS 2013 Update 3 the routing stopped working and I cannot get it to work again. When creating a path like this

```
{ 
  route: 'user/newadvert', 
  moduleId: 'user/newadvert', 
  title: 'New Advert', 
  nav: true, 
  hash: "#../user/newadvert", 
  authorize: ["User", "Administrator"] 
},
```

the system wants to redirect to `//user/newadvert` instead of `/user/newadvert`.

If I type the correct path the view loads correctly but if I click on the links created it does not work. When I hover my mouse over the link it shows `http://user/newadvert` which is obviously not correct.

What could be wrong?

Comment: I didn't recall the hash or authorize properties and checking in the Durandal starter kit revealed that they are *not* defined for the routes it specifies. So I checked the docs on the Durandal website, and it simply refers us to the source code of the router. When you don't supply a hash property it is generated (router.js:478) so if it were me I'd breakpoint there and see what's being done with the value that you're supplying. That or stop supplying it and allow the generator to do its thing, but perhaps you have a reason for being explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter. I saw that the knockout binding for the path adds an additional / prefix, when I removed it the routing started working again. Not sure why it worked before